# Не удалось установить пакет Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Скачиваю visual studio 2022 (pro), выбрал разработку классических приложений на C++. После установки пишет "Произошла неизвестная ошибка".

**Помогло восстановление**

Журнал:

```
Во время установки произошла ошибка.

Для устранения ошибок, связанных с пакетом, попробуйте сделать следующее.

    1. Найдите способы решения ошибок с помощью URL-адресов, указанных под каждым сообщением об ошибке.
    2. Измените выбранные рабочие нагрузки или компоненты и повторите установку.
    3. Удалите продукт с вашего компьютера и повторите установку.

Если эта ошибка была описана в Сообществе разработчиков, вы можете найти способы решения или обхода ошибки в этом сообществе. Если эта ошибка не описана в сообществе, просим вас сообщить о ней, чтобы разработчики могли найти решения или способы обхода ошибки. Чтобы сообщить о проблеме, нажмите кнопку "Оставить отзыв" в правом верхнем углу Visual Studio Installer.

================================================================================

Не удалось установить пакет "Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.32.31327,chip=x86".
    URL-адрес поиска
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=-2147024894
    Сведения
        Команда выполнена: "c:\windows\syswow64\\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -Noninteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -InputFormat None -Command "& """C:\Data\Programming\C++\Visual Studio 2022\cash\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.32.31327,chip=x86\VCRedistInstall.ps1""" -PayloadDirectory """C:\Data\Programming\C++\Visual Studio 2022\cash\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.32.31327,chip=x86""" -Architecture x86 -Logfile """C:\Users\bloody\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20220615135323_001_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest.log"""; exit $LastExitCode"
        Код возврата: -2147024894
        Сведения о коде возврата: Не удается найти указанный файл.
    Журнал
        C:\Users\bloody\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20220615135323_001_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest.log
    Затронутые рабочие нагрузки
        Разработка классических приложений на C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop,version=17.2.32526.322)
    Затронутые компоненты
        MSVC версии 143 — VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 Build Tools (последняя версия) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64,version=17.2.32408.312)
        Базовые компоненты для классических приложений на C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Core,version=17.2.32408.312)
        Обновление для распространяемого компонента C++ 2022 (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.14.Latest,version=17.2.32408.312)
        Отладчик графики и профилировщик GPU для DirectX (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Tools,version=17.2.32408.312)
        Средства CMake C++ для Windows (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project,version=17.2.32408.312)
        Средства профилирования C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.DiagnosticTools,version=17.2.32408.312)
```

Comment: И правда, в чем же проблема ```Сведения о коде возврата: Не удается найти указанный файл.```

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Но у меня есть файл "powershell.exe"

Comment: А он на него и не ругается :) вы внимательно посмотрите лог :) там все по русски написано :)

Comment: И как мне скачать этот microsoft.visualcpp.redist.14.latest... ???

Comment: Можно ручками скачать с сайта майкрософта, можно с трекеров скачать, можно с файлопомоек, выбор за вами :)

Comment: Странная ситуация была. Сам пакет оказывается у меня был. Но почему-то ide его не видела. Помогло восстановление. @ВладимирКлыков все равно спасибо.